# How to bind texture image on Wired sphere using jogl?

Tags: jogl

I can able to create Wired Sphere using GLUT ,Now i want to bind one texture image on the sphere,can any one tell me how to do it.If u can pls provide me some code snippet?
regards,
s.kumaran.

Answer (score 0):

For all who may later find this the same way I did...
Excellent tutorial here: http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jogl/

Comment: That tutorial has holes in it. It's missing key elements when it talks about rendering textures to the sphere

Comment: @SpicyWeenie Ok, so perhaps not an excellent tutorial. But it does answer the question.

Comment: It was good until it came to adding the texture. Thats where the author omitted key methods. But its all good :)